# Run Java source from Linux on local Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have some java source that gets build on a Linux machine using ant.  I want to be able to create eclipse projects for this source so I can debug it on my local pc.  What is the best approach for this?  I'm running Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import a project into Eclipse from an Ant Build File. You may try the following steps

1. Click on File->New->Project
2. Select "Java Project from existing Ant Buildfile" and click "next"
3. Enter a project name, and select the build file to use to create the project
4. Select the javac declaration to be used to define the project
5. Click finish